# Extend my tourist visa toward the end of my "declared" trip or wait until closer to the visa expiration?

Tags: visas, chile, visa-extensions

When I came to Chile, I originally thought I would only be here for 1 month, so that's what I put on my tourist card.

However, now there's a good chance I'm going to stay the full 90 days that my tourist visa allows, and I might even want to extend my visa after that.

Can I wait until the 2.5 month mark to extend my visa, or do I need to extend it 2 weeks before my "declared" trip ends (i.e., within the next 2 weeks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your visa says you're allowed to stay in the country for 90 days, then you're allowed to stay in the country for 90 days, and you only need to apply for an extension once that limit draws near.  What you wrote on the card was only an application for a visa, and is now irrelevant since you've been granted a longer stay than you originally asked for.